# Google Adsense in homepage footer PHPBB 3.2 for logged out users

Tags: php, adsense, phpbb3

Good day folks
I am running PHPbb 3.2 forum software and am interested to know if it's possible to add Google Adsense to the footer of PHPBB3 forum, but Only for Logged Out Users, ie anyone not registered will see adsense?

Will it need to go in overall footer html somewhere or more complex area with php session or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will go into overall_footer.html

To show to only users not logged in, wrap your code in the following conditional...

```
<!-- IF not S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
    put your code here
<!-- ENDIF -->
```